# Downloading a Feature

Tags: drush, features

I may be thinking about this the wrong way, but I would like to download a feature that is already created. I know how to create a feature and download it, but how do you download a feature that already exists so you can use it on another site? Preferably in Drush.

I'm using Drupal 7.50. Thanks!

Edit: I figured out that in the UI, if you create "recreate", you can download it from there. How can this be done in drush though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use my very favorite drush command:

`drush fu your_feature`

This is the same as using "recreate" in the UI except that it will update your feature directly where it resides in your code base (usually at /sites/all/modules/your_feature).

Now you can copy that folder (or zip it up if you like) and use it on any site you'd like.